# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET - Google Chrome Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I attempt to go to any website on Google Chrome on Windows 10, I get the error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET. I tried uninstalling, and reinstalling chrome, netsh winsock reset, made sure the IP and DNS settings were set automatically and flushed IP in command prompt. Interestingly, Microsoft Edge works on it but chrome, no. Any ideas what is wrong?W

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cmd

```
 ipconfig -release

 ipconfig -renew

 ipconfig -flushdns

 ipconfig -registerdns

 nbtstat -rr

 netsh int ip reset all

 netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your pc....

Comment: Do you mean to say **Restart** ?